# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'source_id', table 'source_ingest'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: spring-boot

Entity:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@Table(name = "source_ingest")
public class SourceIngestEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="source_id")
    private Integer sourceId;

    @Column(name="creation_user")
    private String creationUser;

    @Column(name="last_update_user")
    private String lastUpdateUser;
    public SourceIngestEntity() {
    }

    public SourceIngestEntity(Integer sourceId, String creationUser, String lastUpdateUser) {
        this.sourceId = sourceId;
        this.creationUser = creationUser;
        this.lastUpdateUser = lastUpdateUser;
    }

    public Integer getSourceId() {
        return sourceId;
    }

    public void setSourceId(Integer sourceId) {
        this.sourceId = sourceId;
    }

    public String getCreationUser() {
        return creationUser;
    }

    public void setCreationUser(String creationUser) {
        this.creationUser = creationUser;
    }

    public String getLastUpdateUser() {
        return lastUpdateUser;
    }

    public void setLastUpdateUser(String lastUpdateUser) {
        this.lastUpdateUser = lastUpdateUser;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SourceIngestEntity{" +
                "sourceId=" + sourceId +
                ", creationUser='" + creationUser + '\'' +
                ", lastUpdateUser='" + lastUpdateUser + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface SourceIngestRepository extends CrudRepository<SourceIngestEntity, Integer>{
    @Query(value = "select * from source_ingest where source_id=:sourceId", nativeQuery = true )
    List<SourceIngestEntity> findOneBySourceId(@Param("sourceId") int sourceId);
    @Modifying
    @Query(value="INSERT INTO source_ingest (source_id, creation_user, last_update_user) VALUES (:sourceId, :creationUser, :lastUpdateUser)", nativeQuery = true)
    @Transactional
    void createSourceIngest(
            @Param("sourceId") Integer sourceId,
            @Param("creationUser") String creationUser, @Param("lastUpdateUser") String lastUpdateUser);
```

Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SourceAllServices {
    @Autowired
    private SourceIngestRepository sourceIngestRepository;
    public List<SourceIngestEntity> getSourceIngestBySourceId(int sourceId) {
        return sourceIngestRepository.findOneBySourceId(sourceId);
    }
    public SourceIngestEntity createSourceIngest(int sourceId1, int sourceId2) {
        List<SourceIngestEntity> sourceIngestEntities = sourceIngestRepository.findOneBySourceId(sourceId1);
        for (SourceIngestEntity sourceIngestEntity : sourceIngestEntities) {
            SourceIngestEntity newEntity = new SourceIngestEntity();
            newEntity.setSourceId(sourceId2);
            newEntity.setCreationUser(sourceIngestEntity.getCreationUser());
            newEntity.setLastUpdateUser(sourceIngestEntity.getLastUpdateUser());
            sourceIngestRepository.save(newEntity);
        }
        return sourceIngestEntities.get(0);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Autowired
    private SourceAllServices sourceAllServices;

    @GetMapping("/{sourceId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, List<?>>> getSourceIngestBySourceId(@PathVariable int sourceId) {
        Map<String, List<?>> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("sourceIngest", sourceAllServices.getSourceIngestBySourceId(sourceId));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(result);
    }

    @PostMapping("/copy")
    public ResponseEntity<String> copySourceData(
            @RequestParam("sourceId1") int sourceId1,
            @RequestParam("sourceId2") int sourceId2,
            @RequestBody SourceIngestEntity sourceIngestEntity) {

        SourceIngestEntity insertedEntity = sourceAllServices.createSourceIngest(sourceId1, sourceId2);

        if (insertedEntity != null) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                    .body("Data from sourceId1 has been copied to sourceId2 with ID: " + insertedEntity.getSourceId());
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                    .body("No data found for sourceId1: " + sourceId1);
        }
    }
```

Post endpoint: http://localhost:8086/source/copy?sourceId1=100297&sourceId2=100405
json:
{
"creationUser": "xxx",
"lastUpdateUser": "xxx"
}

I should insert sourceId1 data which is avilable in record and sourceId2 where there is no data in a record getting error as ERROR [XNIO-3 task-1] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'source_id', table 'source_ingest'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
ERROR [XNIO-3 task-1] i.u.request UT005023: Exception handling request to /source/copy

need to fix as sourceId2 value as 100405 and rest data in it